# How to properly address Images and assets in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

i am totaly newbi in sveltekit,

my main question is : Where to put images with SvelteKit? and how use it.
in static folder, right?

But this causes a problem:
when in this route : "@domain/dashboard" ,I use this code:

```
<img src="user.png" />
```

it try to find it in @domain/user.png and everything is ok!
but when i use this route: @domain/users/1
it try to find it in @domain/users/user.png exept @domain/user.png.

please help me.

ps: i see there is topics that recommend use something like this:

```
import logo from '$lib/assets/user.png';
```

so if i copy images into lib folder, What is the reason for static folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the link work anywhere, you just have to make the path absolute, by starting with a `/` (and possibly the [`base`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-paths-base), if the application is to be hosted on a sub-path of the server).

```html
<img src="/user.png" />

<!--
  For example for static sites for GitHub pages which are on:
  https://[user-name].github.io/[repository-name]/

  base should be set to '/[repository-name]'
-->
<img src="{base}/user.png" />
```

Things in `static` are available to be referenced *as is*.

---

Everything in `lib` is intended for import, which allows for the possibility of transforming the asset first. E.g. style sheets in a language that has to be preprocessed such as SCSS.

Importing the asset also ensures that a hash is added which helps with cache invalidation, in case the resource can change.

```html
<script>
  import userSrc from '$lib/images/user.png';
</script>
<img src={userSrc} />
```

Comment: You have saved me a lot of time, thanks for sharing your knowledge :x

Comment: @NeoAnderson: Glad it helped. I just added another note that might be relevant, regarding caching of assets.